# Color heatmap based on grouping (or class) in python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, heatmap

Can anyone help me produce a colored correlation matrix based on class so that I can see clusters. I have a nparray with the values and another nparray with that contains each element's class colour (hex color code). How can I make a heatmap that has the correlation values for each cell, but colored by the class (six different colors). Here is an example. [image: heatmap]

This [How to create predefined color range in Matplotlib heat map from a Pandas Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29138951/how-to-create-predefined-color-range-in-matplotlib-heat-map-from-a-pandas-datafr) seems to be relevant, however, the solution simply used a pre-defined cmap. I am able to produce a pcolor plot, however the colours don't seem to correlate to the cluster labels. I think the cmap assignment is wrong.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import *
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

cpool=['#23525f','#f271c4','#33cccc','#e11212','#bf7300','#f2ea30']
correlations = pd.DataFrame.corr(whisky.iloc[:,2:14].transpose())
correlations = np.array(correlations)  #86x86 np.array

correlation_colors = []
for i in range(len(distilleries)):
    for j in range(len(distilleries)):
        if correlations[i,j] < 0.7:                    # if low correlation,
            correlation_colors.append('#f9f9f9')         # just use white. add to the empty array
        else:                                          # otherwise,
            if whisky.Group[i] == whisky.Group[j]:     # if the groups match,
                correlation_colors.append(cpool[whisky.Group[i]]) # color them by their mutual group (class) 0-5
            else:                                      # otherwise
                correlation_colors.append('#e4e1ff') # color them lightgray

corr_color=np.array(correlation_colors).reshape(86,86)
colmap=matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(corr_color)
plt.pcolor(correlations,c=corr_color,cmap=colmap)
```

Comment: @Spencer_Trinh were you able to create your heatmap?, I'm looking forward to make something similar.